# Undefined variable: events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This is my `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     $events = App\Event::all();
     return view('events.index')->withEvent($events);
});
```

And this my view file: ***index.blade.php***

```
<body>
    <h1>{{ count($events) }} Events</h1>

    @foreach($events as $event)
        <article>
            <h1>{{ $event->name }}</h1>
            <p>{{ $event->description }}</p>
            <p>{{ $event->price }} euros</p>
            <p>Lieu :{{ $event->location }}</p>
        </article>
        <hr>
    @endforeach
</body>
```

I got this error during run time:

> Undefined variable: events (View:
>   /home/pangraf/events/resources/views/events/index.blade.php)

Comment: try this out `return view('events.index')->withEvents($events);`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
return view('events.index', compact('events'));
```

instead of

```
return view('events.index')->withEvent($events);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

try remove **s** from `$events` variable..

```
$event = App\Event::all();
return view('events.index')->withEvent($event);
```

second way

```
$event = App\Event::all();
return view('events.index')->with(['event' => $event]);
```

third way

```
$event = App\Event::all();
return view('events.index',compact('event'));
```